# Why doesn't NMinimize work with NSolve?

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization, numerics

Why does NMinimize throw the error and how to fix it?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

eq[chi_, t_, a_, b_, gamma_, beta_] := 
  a*(t - 315)*(chi)^(1/gamma) + 
   b*(chi)^(1/gamma + 1/beta)*1000^(1/beta) - 1;

Chi[t_, a_, b_, gamma_, beta_] := 
 NSolve[eq[chi, t, a, b, gamma, beta] == 0, chi, Reals][[1, 1, 2]]

Chi[155, 0.7, 0.008, 1.6, 0.5]

(*0.12029*)

min[a_, b_, gamma_, 
  beta_] := (Chi[131, a, b, gamma, beta] - 62)^2

min[0.7, 0.008, 1.6, 0.5]

(*3828.06*)

NMinimize[Evaluate@min[a, b, gamma, beta], {a, b, gamma, beta}]

(*During evaluation of In[7]:= 
ToBoxes[Refresh[Internal`MessageMenu["NSolve", "nsmet", 2, 7, 1, 34328787444913064695, "Local"], None], StandardForm]NSolve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to NSolve.*)
```

Comment: WHen typing `min[a,b,gamma,beta]` Mathematica says `NSolve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to NSolve.`  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5ggD.png)  which is what you also show at the end. So need to solve this problem first before NMinimize can work

Comment: @Nasser, thanks for the comment! But I don't understand, what is the wrong with the function `min[a,b,gamma,beta]`? `NSolve` return `chi` for example in this case `min[0.7, 0.008, 1.6, 0.5]`

Comment: But `min[0.7,0.008,1.6,0.5]` and `min[a,b,gamma,beta]` are not the same? First case you are passing numerical values, in the second you are not. NDSolve sees the equation to solve as `-1+1000^(1/beta) b chi^(1/beta+1/gamma)-184 a chi^(1/gamma)==0` in the second case, while in the first case it sees the equation as `-1-128.8 chi^0.625+8000. chi^2.625==0` that is the difference.

Comment: @Nasser, thanks! Yes, I agree, but doesn't `NMinimize` substitute certain variable values into the function `min[a,b,gamma,beta]`?

Comment: The issue is that NSolve is called before `NMinimize` sees the input. So it is NSolve that is generating the error, not `NMinimize`.

Comment: This either works better, or takes much longer to fail (I don't have the patience to find out). `Chi[t_?NumberQ, a_?NumberQ, b_?NumberQ, gamma_?NumberQ, 
  beta_?NumberQ] := 
 NSolveValues[eq[chi, t, a, b, gamma, beta] == 0, chi, Reals][[1]]
min[a_?NumberQ, b_?NumberQ, gamma_?NumberQ, 
  beta_?NumberQ] := (Chi[131, a, b, gamma, beta] - 62)^2` Might work faster if you give ranges to the parameters.